# How Should we know the DMV got flushed in Microsoft sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Hi i am using SQL Server and i would like to know whether DMV got flushed and when?

Comment: Which DMV are you using?

Comment: i am using all DMV's to capture the background process of SQL Server

Comment: yes in my process every day we flush it 10 times and i wanted to know when it is get flushed.

Comment: Si, if you "flush it" 10 times a day, don't you already know *when* it got "flushed"?

Comment: nope because we need DMV's data correct if we flush then we can get the correct data.so is there any table where we can have details about DMV flush, i used this query to flush DMV data DBCC FREEPROCINDB(db_id).

Comment: We're not talking about the department of motor vehicles are we?

Comment: nope, because flush code is run by the app developers. @Lamak

Comment: @VikrantMore I'm hoping they're not doing this in the production environment.

Comment: @swasheck yes we are doing it at our production environment, we are collecting DMV's data insted of Profiler as profiler hampers DB server performance. to collect exact counter from DMV we need to use DBCC FREEPROCINDB(db_id) to clear it. not all DMV's.

Comment: @VikrantMore why are you doing this is production? and why are developers given this authority? are you testing in production???

Comment: @swasheck i am testing it in test enviornment and applying it on production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to reset the counters in DMVs? [Because what you're doing is you're clearing the plan cache in that DB](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2007/09/29/geek-city-clearing-a-single-plan-from-cache.aspx). That's not going to be really helpful for doing what you say you are trying to do.

Now if you're really actually trying to reset DMV performance counters, you'll want to use `DBCC SQLPERF('sys.dmv_name_here',CLEAR);`. I suppose the way you could validate that it worked would be to query the DMV before and after running `SQLPERF` and noting that the counters actually dropped.

--

EDIT

--

Upon reflection, you may be trying to zero your plan cache stats when you flush the plan cache. When you flush the plan, I'm assuming that the plan handle will be either removed or would become useless. I have to run to a change control meeting so I can't test this theory yet, but I will when I return. At any rate, if you want to blow out the stats for plan cache after you've flushed the plan cache you'd want to run

```
DBCC SQLPERF('sys.dm_exec_cached_plans', CLEAR);
```

in the database that you're flushing.

Comment: right, but in the book of "SQL Server Starter Pack" they where using DBCC FREEPROCINDB(db_id) to clean as we are running and flushing DMV SQLPERF can affect to other DMV part at production server. so we would like to know the at what time last DMV get flushed by DBCC FREEPROCINDB(db_id) by application developer.

Comment: I'll see what I can find about the scope of each DMV.

Comment: basically we are flushing DMV's sys.dm_exec_* so by making join we will get last time executed data.